# Async-await not working as I expected in forEach loop

Tags: javascript, foreach, async-await

I am using WebRTC to try and connect two users together. I call createOffer then I set the local description of the peer connection using what createOffer returns. I don't know why I am getting the following error:

**Note: I am using firebase firestore as a signaling server**

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Cannot set local offer when
> createOffer has not been called.

Here is my code:

```
async function preformSignaling() {
  let users = await negDoc.collection("users").get();
  let newPeerConnection;

  users.forEach(async (doc) => {
    if (isNotAlreadyConnected(doc.id)) {
      newPeerConnection = new UserConnection(servers, doc.id);

      if (doc.id != sessionStorage.getItem("userID") && doc.id != "metadata") {

        let connOfferDescription =
          await newPeerConnection.userPeerConnection.createOffer();

        await newPeerConnection.userPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(
          connOfferDescription
        );

        await doc.collection("offer-candidates").doc("offer").set({
          offer: newPeerConnection.userPeerConnection.localDescription,
        });
      }

      peerConnections.push(newPeerConnection);
    }
  });
}

class UserConnection {
  constructor(servers, remoteUserID) {
    this.userPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
    this.remoteStream = new MediaStream();
    this.remoteUserID = remoteUserID;
  }

  getRemoteUserID() {
    return this.remoteUserID;
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems possible you've confused the async parts of your app. For instance calls like `await newPeerConnection` when the methods have no return value is a warning flag.

Comment: @RandyCasburn But I don't use those methods and I'm still having the same issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm taking a bit of a blind stab here but using async-await in a `forEach` (or map,filter,reduce etc.) is a common gotcha. It essentially just fires a bunch of async calls.

It won't wait for what's happening in that callback to finish before firing the next one. The internals of the `forEach` would need to await the callback and the callback must return a promise.

Because you have `let newPeerConnection` outside of the loop, you are probably writing that variable multiple times before any of the `createOffer` calls finish.

You could bring that variable inside the loop if none of these simultaneous calls will affect each other. Otherwise, just use a for-of loop if you'd like to run them one by one. That might look something like this:

```js
async function preformSignaling() {
    let users = await negDoc.collection('users').get();
    let newPeerConnection;

    for (let doc of users) {
        if (!isNotAlreadyConnected(doc.id)) continue;

        newPeerConnection = new UserConnection(servers, doc.id);

        if (
            doc.id !== sessionStorage.getItem('userID') &&
            doc.id !== 'metadata'
        ) {
            let connOfferDescription =
                await newPeerConnection.userPeerConnection.createOffer();

            await newPeerConnection.userPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(
                connOfferDescription
            );

            await doc.collection('offer-candidates').doc('offer').set({
                offer: newPeerConnection.userPeerConnection.localDescription,
            });
        }

        peerConnections.push(newPeerConnection);
    }
}
```

> Note a couple of minor changes in there for better practices: !== not !=, and check the inverse of the bool and continue early to avoid the pyramid of doom.